# FillText not working

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm unable to get the text on the canvas. What am I doing wrong here ?

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qHpt6/

```
var el = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var context = el.getContext('2d');

context.globalAlpha = 0.95;
context.beginPath();
context.rect(0, 0, el.width, el.height);
context.fillStyle = "#435a6b";
context.fillText('Hello World',0,0);
context.fill();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to draw 40 point text into a little teeny box. Make the box bigger or the text a lot smaller.

You're also drawing the text at the upper left corner of the box. The text goes **up** from the baseline.

If you change the box size to something like 350 wide and 250 high, and change the code to

```
context.fillText("Hello World", 0, 200);
```

then you'll see the text.

[Forked and fixed fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Rp6Av/)

Comment: thank you pointy, did not know that the text was going above the baseline

Comment: @user1184100 if you want to draw the text from top you can use `context.textBaseline = 'top'`.

Answer (score 7):

There is multiple issues:

1. The canvas is too small too correctly draw the text.
2. The text has the same `fillStyle` as the rectangle, so one cannot see it.
3. You draw the rectangle **after** the text, so the text is covered.

You may try this code:

```js
    context.globalAlpha = 0.95;
    context.rect(0, 0, el.width, el.height);
    context.fillStyle = "#435a6b";
    context.fill();
    
    context.font = 'italic 40pt Calibri';
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.fillText('Hello World',50,50);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qHpt6/